# Sql Query: How to Base on the row name to display

Tags: sql

I have the table data as listed on below:

```
name  | score
andy  | 1
leon  | 2
aaron | 3
```

I want to list out as below, even no jacky's data, but list his name and score set to 0

```
aaron    3
andy     2
jacky    0
leon     2
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ... You should always tag your SQL questions with your DBMS. Then, where does jacky come from? Is this name in another table or how come it's in your result?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but the following is 100% standard ANSI SQL:

```
select v.name, coalesce(t.score, 0) as score
from (
  values ('andy'),('leon'),('aaron'),('jacky')
) as v(name)
  left join your_table t on t.name = v.name;
```

The `values` clause builds up a "virtual table" that contains the names you are interested in. Then this is used in a left join so that all names from the virtual table are returned plus the existing scores from your (unnamed table). For non-existing scores, `NULL` is returned which is turned to `0` using `coalesce()`

If you only want to specify the missing names, you can use a UNION in the virtual table:

```
select v.name, coalesce(t.score, 0) as score
from (
  select t1.name
  from your_table t1
  union 
  select * 
  from ( values ('jacky')) as x
) as v(name)
  left join your_table t on t.name = v.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed the query, could list out the data, but still missing jacky, only could list out as shown on below, the DBMS. In SQL is SQL2008.

data
name    score   scoredate
andy    1   2021-08-10 01:23:16
leon    2   2021-08-10 03:25:16
aaron   3   2021-08-10 06:25:16
andy    4   2021-08-10 11:25:16
leon    5   2021-08-10 13:25:16

result set
name   | score
aaron  | 1
andy   | 5
leon   | 7

```
select v.name as Name,
coalesce(sum(t.score),0) as Score 
from (
values ('aaron'), ('andy'), ('jacky'), ('leon')
) as v(name)
left join Score t on t.name=v.name
where scoredate>='2021-08-10  00:00:00'
and scoredate<='2021-08-10  23:59:59'
group by v.name
order by v.name asc
```

Comment: This, as well as your other "answer", is not an answer to your original question. Please delete it. Accept a_horse_with_no_name's answer. Generally: Open a new request in order to ask another question. As to this query: Do you know what an outer join does? It joins even when there is no matching row (jacky in your example). The joined values are null in such rows. In your `WHERE` clause you want a certain scoredate range. NULL is not within this range. jacky gets dismissed. Solution: You must make the scoredate criteria part of the `ON` clause. It is join criteria.

Comment: Is SQL2008 supposed to be SQL Server 2008? That would be a very old version. Its support ended two years ago. You should not work with such an old software.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a bunch of information, such as where "Jacky"s name comes from.  If you have a list of names that you know are not in the table, just use `union all`:

```
select name, score
from t
union all
select 'Jacky', 0;
```

Comment: jacky's data is from the survey, but some days, will not have all, e,g. on 2021-08-09 have aaron, andy, jacky, leon, but on 2021-08-10, only have aaron, andy, leon, when query the data by date on 2021-08-10, only could list out aaron, andy, leon, just want to list out all name even such date is no such name's data.
e.g. on 2021-08-09
name      score
aaron       1
andy        2
jacky        3
leon         4

on 2021-08-10
name      score
aaron       3
andy        5
leon         7

just want on 2021-08-10, even no jacky's data, lust jacky as 0, always list out all name

Comment: @user . . . Do you have a list of all users that you expect?